# Assess ploidy estimation through SNV and CNV results

Tags: vcf, snp, variant-calling, cnv, allele-frequency

I want to assess ploidy estimation (i.e., diploid vs tetraploid) in a set of samples for which I have both results from the variant caller (i.e., SNVs) and from the copy number caller.

What are the possible approaches that can be used in this case? I know that in some in cases it might be possible to use VAF to assess ploidy estimation, but I haven't found exactly how this (possibly simple) approach is defined.

Note: I already have a caller that I am testing. My question is more related to exploratory data analysis or manual inspection of the caller's results.

VAF distribution examples might be similar to what is done in [CNAqc](https://caravagnalab.github.io/CNAqc/articles/a7_example_MSeq.html#peak-detection) (image below extracted from their online tutorial):
[image: VAF distribution]

Comment: What is the underlying data quality? Would you be able to go in and visually confirm alleles in a single sample in IGV or whatever? Approaches such as [here](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12859-018-2128-z) use allele frequency at heterozygous SNPs in single samples to try to address this question, so I think that's the relevant question. I have to say that I don't understand the figure or the tutorial at first glance, it appears to be looking for de novo mutations (?) and seeing their frequency.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question regarding the tutorial - I'm only interested in plotting the VAF distribution for the different genotypes, that is the first example I could find online to explain one of the tools for the analysis (sorry it that confused you). I will read the paper you linked, thank you.